# Simple HttpAsyncServer does not work in LAN

Tags: c#, visual-studio, server, windows-firewall

I am using `HttpAsyncServer` inside my `Main(...)` to listen on port 8081, locally (I run it from Visual Studio, that is launched as administrator):

```
var server = new HttpAsyncServer(new string[] { "http://192.168.0.101:8081/" });
server.RunServer();
for(; ; )
{
    Thread.Sleep(30000);
}
```

I can access this server from my local machine (the one that creates the server), via `http://192.168.0.101:8081`.

Unfortunately, all other devices in my local network cannot load the page from server.

I've already set up Windows firewall rule to allow incoming/outgoing traffic.
I've also tried changing local IP address of my machine in code to `+`, with the exact same result:

```
var server = new HttpAsyncServer(new string[] { "http://+:8081/" });
```

Comment: this is a bad idea no matter which way you look at it `for(; ; )` `Thread.Sleep(30000)`

Comment: Turn the firewall of to test if this is a problem. Maybe you have additional software that prevents this (Windows Defender?). Are you sure that you have added the rule for the correct network type?

Comment: @DennisKuypers I've added rules for all network types. And the same program works fine with e.g. TCPListener, but not with HttpAsyncServer.

Comment: Maybe this is about [Url Reservations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/http/add-urlacl)